# Nested Form, won't save if child values are blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@ticket,@note])  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: "Note", input_html: {:"x-webkit-speech" => ""} %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :timesheets do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.input :duration, :input_html => { :size => 3, :maxlength => 5 } %> 
    <%= builder.association :work_type, collection: Choice.work_types %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

If I enter a name, duration and work_type into the form, then it saves the Note and the Timesheet. However if I only enter a "Note" and leave the Duration and WorkType empty it errors.

Ideally I want it to just save a note and no Timesheet.

Here are the params being posted

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dd2TRC8cU=", "note"=>{"name"=>"My Note", "timesheets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"duration"=>"", "work_type_id"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Create Note", "type"=>"note", "ticket_id"=>"21"}
```

There is no specific error:

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

EDIT: Models:

```
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :activity

  validates_numericality_of :duration
  validates_numericality_of :work_type_id

end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :timesheets
end
```

Controller

```
def create
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])

  if params[:type]      
    case type
    when "note"
      @activity = @ticket.notes.new(activity_params)
    when "email"
      @activity = @ticket.emails.new(activity_params)
    end
  end

  if @activity.save
    redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Activity was successfully created.'
  else
    # populate variables
    @email = @activity
    @note = @activity
    render action: 'new', error: 'Something went wrong.'
  end
end


def activity_params(action)
  case type
  when 'email'
    activity_params = params.require(:email).permit(:ticket_id, :name, :description, 
                                                    :entity_id, :user_id, :agreement_id, 
                                                    :followup, :type, :from, {:to => []}, 
                                                    {:cc => []}, :draft, {:attachments_attributes => [:file]}, 
                                                    {timesheets_attributes: [:duration, :work_type_id]} )

    # lets convert the array of email addresses to a string
    case action
      when "create"
        activity_params[:to] = activity_params[:to].drop(1).join(", ")
        activity_params[:cc] = activity_params[:cc].drop(1).join(", ")
      when "update"
        activity_params[:to] = activity_params[:to].drop(1).join(", ")
        activity_params[:cc] = activity_params[:cc].drop(1).join(", ")                  
    end

    return activity_params

  when 'note'
    activity_params = params.require(:note).permit(:ticket_id, :name, :description, :entity_id, :user_id, :agreement_id, :followup, :type, {:attachments_attributes => [:file]}, {timesheets_attributes: [:duration, :work_type_id]} )

    return activity_params
  end
end
```

Comment: I have updated the information in the post.

Comment: Have a try with my answer.It should work.

Comment: Post your `activity_params` method.

Comment: Try giving like `if params[:timesheet][:duration].blank? && params[:timesheet][:work_type_id].blank?` then `activity_params = params.require(:email).permit(:ticket_id, :name, :description, 
                                                    :entity_id, :user_id, :agreement_id, 
                                                    :followup, :type, :from, {:to => []}, 
                                                    {:cc => []}, :draft, {:attachments_attributes => [:file]})` in the `activity_params` method

Comment: This seems to have done the trick:

          if activity_params[:timesheets_attributes]["0"][:duration].blank? && activity_params[:timesheets_attributes]["0"][:work_type_id].blank? then 
        activity_params.delete :timesheets_attributes
      end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally I want it to just save a note and no Timesheet

You need to  use **`allow_blank => true`** on the specific fields,so that it saves the record even with the blank values.

In your **`Timesheet model`**,give like this

```
Class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base

....

validates_presence_of :duration, :allow_blank => true

validates_presence_of :work_type_id, :allow_blank => true

end
```

Have a look at **[allow_balnk](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank)** for more information.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! When I do that I end up with a timesheet saved with a blank duration and work_type - if these values are blank then I want no timesheet Saved at all only an Activity.

Comment: @user3565039 Please restart the server after making the changes and try again.

Comment: @user3565039 It does save the timesheet with blank values.If you don't want to save the timesheet record at all,then just remove the fields of timesheet in the form.

Comment: I don't think I have explained it properly.

1. If values are entered then a timesheet should be saved.
2. If no values are entered then no timesheet should be saved.

Comment: @user3565039 How is that possible man!.If no values are entered,then those will save as blank values.

Comment: Timesheet is an association - there is not always a Timesheet on an Activity. One way would be for me to intercept the params hash and check for blank values and them remove them but I am looking for a cleaner option. Man.

Comment: @user3565039 Please post your controller code.I got an idea!

Comment: I have added the "create" method... The controller is quite large in full. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

The final solution:

```
  if activity_params[:timesheets_attributes]["0"][:duration].blank? && activity_params[:timesheets_attributes]["0"][:work_type_id].blank? then 
    activity_params.delete :timesheets_attributes
  end
```